# If light is an EM wave, why don't antennas pick them up?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, light, wave

Or do they get picked up but don't show on spectrum analyzers? Although the photons in light are greater in energy than radio waves!

Wouldn't there be constant noise from light? Even if it's small.

Comment: So if antenna is tuned to the frequency of light, it would pick it up?

Comment: Perhaps I should delete my silly question. I don't know how I missed it. Thanks @Bort

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_rectenna

Comment: The photoreceptor cells (rods and cones) in our eyes are antennas for visible light :)

Comment: Check out this Google search on this very subject:  https://www.google.com/search?q=antennas+for+light

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. The antennas have to be very small so you need a lot of them, but using antennas + rectifiers ([optical rectennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_rectenna)) is a plausible way of converting light energy to electrical current.

The structures have to be made with a process that has a resolution finer than a wavelength of light, which is tricky since light is the photo in photolithography, but we are getting down there in resolution by various methods such as using shorter wavelengths and more sophisticated gambits.

Similar (but cruder) methods have been proposed to convert microwave energy transmitted from [space-based solar power stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-based_solar_power) to electrical energy on earth. The energy density would be kept low enough that it would not be as much of a death ray as you might think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will be reading more about optical rectennas for light energy harvesting.

Comment: Another Question of interest, are there antennas that can receive a certain frequency and convert it to another frequency at transmission? Is the possible?

Comment: It takes more than an antenna to convert frequency. One almost passive approach is to use a nonlinear element, for example, a KTP  (potassium titanyl phosphate) crystal, which can double the light frequency.

Comment: "receive a certain frequency and convert it to another frequency at transmission" - this is done with light all the time with fluorescent coatings, such as in white LEDs and fluorescent tube lamps. Or do you want the radio case?

Comment: @pjc50 I was interested in studying LEDs and still am after this question confirmed their uses in light spectrum. However would other means than attenuating media such as crystals work for light to radio frequency change?

Comment: Light to RF is many orders of magnitude frequency change.

Comment: You want something like the phosphors that @pjc50 mentions that emit RF? Seems unlikely but I can't think of a physical reason why it's impossible.

Comment: Technically anything that gets hot under a light will start emitting RF in some quantity, which is useful for microwave astronomers but has few earthly applications. *Where are you going with this idea*?

Comment: @pjc50 I'm new to the EM comms region and basically exploring all areas related in physics and electrical engineering that come to mind, from Quantum to Macro concepts. It's 3am here, and I woke up to ask the question which popped in my mind 

Comment: My crazy ideas were influenced by Quantum Physics, Quantum makes you a different person. (Don't know in a good or bad way... I'm yet to find out).

Answer (score 3):

Effective antennas must have about the size of a quarter of the wavelength (rule of thumb).

For visible light wavelength is about 400-800nm.

So you can imagine how small those antennas for visible light must be: They have the size of molecules. They *are* molecules. And in fact if substances are colored the molecules are antennas "tuned" to particular frequencies of EM radiation in the visible range. Although in most cases absorbed energy is converted to mechanical energy (i.e. rotation and/or vibration of the molecules eventually heating up the substance) not to electical energy.

The energy doesn't show up on converntional spectrum analyzers because of their limited badnwidth ;-)

Special spectrum analyzers for EM radiation in the range of visible light are called [optical spectrometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_spectrometer).

Comment: Thanks Curd. You raised a good point on bandwidth. Can we safely define bandwidth as the amount of photons in any given wave?

Comment: @Rain, you're asking lots of follow-up questions. But this isn't a discussion site. We don't like to follow up endlessly in comments. If you have a new question, click the "Ask Question" button and ask. (But in this case about bandwidth vs the number of photons in a wave, please do some research first)

Comment: @ThePhoton I thought it was better not to open too many separate questions, but I can divide them in future. Of course I ask about photons because not even physicist can tell me what they are other than the fact that they are propagators of EM. Where others say they 'are' the EM. And EM fields same. But I guess all my photon questions can be asked separately. Thank you for guiding new members

Comment: @Rain: no, bandwidth corresponds to color (frequency; which is proportional to energy per phoon); not amount of photons.

Answer (score 2):

Your antenna surely picks the light until it's a mirror. Unfortunately ordinary circuits made of wire, capacitors, transistors etc. are too big to notice the resulted current. They are heavily out of the right tuning. Try a photodiode as an integrated antenna and detector. You can increase the effectiveness of your antenna by adding a lens or concave reflecting mirror.

Need some frequency selectivity as in radio receivers? Buy a colored filter. Too weak signal - need an amplifier BEFORE the detector? No problem. Insert a laser in it's original form without the resonating mirrors that make it an oscillator that do not amplify, but generate light.

**Addition due the comment** that asked "can antenna convert the frequency?"

An antenna is not considered to have an ability to convert the frequency- it only catches the wave and feeds it to some unit that converts the frequency. The frequency converter is a mixer with another input from an oscillator. About 25 years ago the general talking changed. When one went to a shop to buy a satellite antenna for his tv, he assumed to get also the frequency converter from microwave to normal tv channel. To minimize the signal loss it's best to do the frequency downshift for the tv as soon as possible.Thus the mixer+oscillator is in the antenna

**Not asked, but maybe nice to know**: There exist materials that convert the frequency. Some fluorescent materials absorb light or ultraviolet. Absobrtion causes electron orbit exitations that reverse, but do not collapse exactly to the same. They produce radiation that has a different wavelength. The color in safety vests has a wide input band, but the output band is narrow which causes a high color contrast.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I guess I can ask you this question too,, are there antennas that can receive a certain frequency and convert it to another frequency at transmission? Is the possible?

Comment: @Rain A rectenna is exactly a *radio-frequency mixer*. By using heterodyne principle, two light sources of differing wavelength (frequency) shining on its surface can produce a radio-frequency difference signal. So yes, frequency conversion is possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Wouldn't there be constant noise from light? Even if it's small.

Infra red light creates heat and that in turn creates noise in any circuit that has resistance. See [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise).

The formula is: -

[image]

> Or do they get picked up but don't show on spectrum analyzers?

Visible light is in the range 400,000-800,000 GHz - I don't think there are many conventional "radio" spectrum analysers that will work up to this range: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you, someone also mentioned Bandwidth of light which could also be why analyzers would not see it even if it were to go up to those frequencies.

Comment: What's unconventional about this type of optical spectrum analyzer?http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/5963-7145E.pdf

Comment: @glen_geek yes, maybe a better word than "conventional" is needed. How about radio spectrum analysers?

Comment: I confess that knowing at what wavelength/frequency "radio" ends and "optical" begins eludes me. Seems to be a moving and overlapping target.

Comment: You're right, @glen_geek.  They are one and the same, just different frequencies.  One section is called optical simply because our eyes are sensitive to them.